# looking for duplicate values within multiple columns mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I would love to find a simple query to find duplicate values across more that one column in
a table.

table example:

```
PK, FK, Animal1, Animal2
001, 100, Dog, Cat
002, 100, Dog, Bird
003, 100, Rat, Mouse
004, 100, Fish, Dog
005, 200, Dog, Mouse
```

I want to find the rows where "Dog" is duplicated in both Animal1 and Animal2.  So, in this case it would return 001, 002, 004... FK 100 can only select Dog once.

Comment: I don't understand the question. How is `Dog` duplicated in row `001`?

Comment: Use `UNION` to unpivot `Animal1` and `Animal2` into a single column. Then you can count duplicates with `GROUP BY FK, Animal`

Comment: Dog can only exist once for FK 100.  So 001, 002, and 004 all contain the duplicated value of Dog.  Where 001 and 005 are OK because they are not connect to the same FK.  and 003 is OK because both Animal1 and Animal2 are not repeated anywhere else for FK 100.

Comment: was using this, but it only finds dups in Animal1 and struggling to find a way to get both columns included.

SELECT a.*
FROM Animals a
JOIN (SELECT FK, Animal1, COUNT(*)
FROM Animals 
GROUP BY FK, Animal1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) b
ON a.FK = b.FK
AND a.Animal1 = b.Animal1
ORDER BY a.FK;

Answer (score 0):

this code identifies non-unique (FK,Animal) combinations:

```
select FK, Animal, count(a.PK) count from (
    select PK, FK, Animal1 Animal from table1
    union
    select PK, FK, Animal2 from table1) a
group by FK, Animal
```

and this other fetches all the rows with non-unique (FK,Animal) combinations:

```
select * from table1
where FK = (select FK from (
            select FK, Animal, count(a.PK) count from (
                select PK, FK, Animal1 Animal from table1 union
                select PK, FK, Animal2 from table1) a
            group by FK, Animal
            having count(*) > 1 ) b )
  and ( Animal1 = (select Animal from (
            select FK, Animal, count(a.PK) count from (
                select PK, FK, Animal1 Animal from table1 union
                select PK, FK, Animal2 from table1) a
            group by FK, Animal
            having count(*) > 1 ) b )
   or   Animal2 = (select Animal from (
            select FK, Animal, count(a.PK) count from (
                select PK, FK, Animal1 Animal from table1 union
                select PK, FK, Animal2 from table1) a
            group by FK, Animal
            having count(*) > 1 ) b )
  )
```

dbfiddle with intermediate steps [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4446f7402dce6edef44992db7b663fe5) (MySQL 8.0)

Comment: This is great! Is there a way to show the full primary set of records? So instead of : 
 FK, Animal, Count  001, Dog, 3  I could just get the records: 001, 100, Dog, Cat 002, 100, Dog, Bird 004, 100, Fish, Dog As you can see I'm new here... still need to learn how to make my comments format nicely like yours and BarMar above. My apologies if it is hard to read.

Comment: Thanks for the further comment, @dongalino , perfectly nice to read. I added a new version, now bringing the original rows having repeated values for FK,Animal.

Comment: Hi Isis.  This is a brilliant query.  Thank you so much for your help.  I worked great on the test data but when I converted it to my DB with 25000 rows there were more that one set up duplicates and it returns a "Subquery returns more than 1 row" error.  I added a second duplicate set of records to your test queries in dbfiddle and I think it runs into the same issue.  I don't see the error message but no rows returned in the final query.  I tried to mess around with it but did not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a simple self-`UNION`.

E.g. if there was a row with `Dog, Dog`, and you need both columns, include each Animal column without matching aliases but you'll need to filter each column using `OR`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM animals_table 
UNION
SELECT * FROM animals_table) AS animals
WHERE animals.Animal1 = 'Dog'
OR animals.Animal2 = 'Dog';
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0853b/4/0)

If you wanted only `PK`, `FK`, and whichever animal value that matches 'Dog' in a single row, you could instead use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT animals_tt.PK, animals_tt.FK, animals_tt.Animal1 AS all_animals FROM animals_tt 
UNION 
SELECT animals_tt.PK, animals_tt.FK, animals_tt.Animal2 AS all_animals FROM animals_tt) AS animals
WHERE animals.all_animals = 'Dog';
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0853b/3)

That `UNION` clause creates a table with both animal columns in a single column called `all_animals`:

```
PK, FK, all_animals

001, 100, Dog

002, 100, Dog

003, 100, Rat

004, 100, Fish

005, 200, Dog
-------------------- 
001, 100, Cat

002, 100, Bird

003, 100, Mouse

004, 100, Dog

005, 200, Mouse
```

From there we use that single WHERE statement to filter to just rows with 'Dog'.